# HttpWebRequest Error on Server works Locally

Tags: asp.net, web-services, httpwebrequest, asp.net-web-api, load-balancing

I have a shopping cart that acts as a general handler for different, disconnected parts of my application to allow users to purchase items. When the user removes an item from their cart, the cart then needs to inform the service that added the item. I'd hoped to use web services to accomplish this.

I am using an HttpWebRequest that looks like this:

```
        Dim serializer As New JavaScriptSerializer
        Dim req As HttpWebRequest
        Dim encoder As New System.Text.UTF8Encoding
        Dim jsonBytes As Byte()
        Dim stream As System.IO.Stream
        Dim result As String = ""
        Dim serialized As String
        Dim request As System.Web.HttpRequest = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request
        Dim resolvedService As String = ResolveUrl(request.Url.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Authority) & Service)
        Dim Success As Boolean = False

        serialized = serializer.Serialize(PurchaseData)
        jsonBytes = encoder.GetBytes(serialized)

        req = WebRequest.Create(resolvedService.Trim)
        req.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8"
        req.Method = "POST"
        req.UseDefaultCredentials = True
        req.ContentLength = jsonBytes.Length
        req.Timeout = "60000"
```

When I use this on my local computer, it works fine. But, when it's running on our host, it fails. If it is over https (which it should be), then I get "The underlying connection was closed: Could not establish trust relationship for the SSL/TLS secure channel." If it is not over https, then it just gives a 404. The requests to the service work through fiddler. There just seems to be an issue with them originating from the host server or something.

I've tried a number of different things and am totally stuck. I've heard it could be an issue with load balancing from my host, but I'm not sure what to do about that.

Does anybody know how I might proceed?

Thanks,

Mike

Comment: Perhaps your web service is using a self-signed SSL certificate that is not trusted by the host?

Comment: No... it's a legitimate certificate... digicert with EV... and it works fine in a browser.